# Sending form information to emails stored in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

I have been researching this but cant sem to get an answer.
I have a form that is sending the info to my database, I also want the info to go to email addresses which are stored in a column in my table in the database. Heres the code, I was just playing around to see if I could do a SELECT query but it wouldnt work, also Iknow that sending the email works when I manually ut an address into my "setTo"

```
require 'mail/class.simple_mail.php';
$mailer = new SimpleMail();

$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'];
$time = $_REQUEST['time'];
$date = $_REQUEST['date'];
$place = $_REQUEST['place'];
$email = "SELECT email FROM bridesmaids";

$message = "<strong>This is an email from the bride to you the bridesmaids, here is the information on the next dress fitting<br />".$date." ".$time." ".$place." ".$comments." </strong>";



$send   = $mailer->setTo('$email', 'Your Email')
                 ->setSubject('Dress Fitting')
                 ->setFrom('donaghy-e5@email.ulster.ac.uk', 'Domain.com')
                 ->addMailHeader('Reply-To', 'donaghy-e5@email.ulster.ac.uk', 'Domain.com')
                 ->addMailHeader('Cc', 'donaghy-e5@email.ulster.ac.uk', 'Bill Gates')
                 ->addGenericHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"')
                 ->setMessage($message)
                 ->setWrap(100)
                 ->send();
echo ($send) ? 'Your Email has been sent to your bridesmaids' : 'Could not send email';
```

Comment: Variables will not be parsed under single quotes , You need to remove them. Write like this.. `$send   = $mailer->setTo($email, 'Your Email')`

Comment: ok, thank you for your response, but I dont think my SELECT query for selecting the enails within the table is working, any ideas?

Comment: You cant use your SELECT query directly for your $email variable

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't created an SQL connection, do this first then:

**1:** Select your emails from your bridesmaids table - then return the results into an array (`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` or `fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`) and bind this array to a variable e.g. `$mailingList`.

**2:** Wrap your mailer code in a `foreach` loop (https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) an example would be:

```
foreach($mailingList as $value) {
    
    // your mailer code here, replace $email with $value
    $send   = $mailer->setTo($value, 'Your Email')
    // $value will update for each iteration with your emails

}
```

**3:** Ensure any code or variables which do not need to be repeated are outside of the loop.

Comment: $value should not be in single quotes there: `$mailer->setTo($value, 'Your Email')`

Comment: Apologies, just copied the line out of the original question, will update

Answer (score 0):

You don't query the database for the actual e-mail adresses. You just have s string that contains an SQL Query but you never actually connect to a database and fetch data using a query.

```
$email = "SELECT email FROM bridesmaids";
```

This should become something like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT email FROM bridesmaids")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: thank you for that, but what do i put as my setTo then?